# Convert .ckpt to .h5

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, resnet

I have trained the model using resnet18 for mask R-CNN detection. For every epoch, it created a ".ckpt" file only.
Now I want to use that .ckpt file as the detector for detecting images. I have python code that takes a ".h5" file for detection.
Please help me with How I can use the ".ckpt" file for detection. or How can I convert it to the ".h5"?
Thanks

I have tried generating ".h5" file instead of ".ckpt" with training process but it did not work for me.
Now I need a way to use ".ckpt" files for detecting objects in Images.

Comment: You can use model.load_weights() to load the weights to model from checkpoint folder to use model again for saving to h5 format . Attached reference [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#checkpoint_callback_options) for reference.